# Tomcat not accessible from EC2 Instance (Ubuntu 14)

Tags: java, tomcat, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am not able to access the tomcat using public IP of EC2 Instance. I can access it using http://localhost:8080 internally but not from outside. In fact, It was running good since 2 months but suddenly it stopped and now I am hanging in between. locally my application is running fine and I can ping to my Instance using Public IP. Security group defines access to all traffic (TCP,HTTP,SSH). Then why Tomcat/Application is not being accessed externally. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Firewall sounds like the most likely explanation.

Comment: @Kayaman What should be done then?

Comment: when I do "telnet $SERVER_IP 80" from external machine(where i want to access my app), it says could not open connection to host this and port this.

Answer (score 2):

You have to define security group rule.

Security Groups -> Inbound -> Edit:

Custom TCP Rule : TCP: 8080 : Source Anywhere

Comment: @Simar, did you get a solution? I'm facing the same issue.

Comment: @Abilash actually few days earlier my account was suspended due to some issues and after that I could not access any of the Instances that were configured before Account Suspension. I contacted to AWS Support but no results. Hence I have to re-configure the Instances. Which is not a proper solution I guess.